# BindingSource filter on related table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I am using vb.net WinForms with SQL Server 2014. I have a form with various textboxes and checkboxes I am populating from the database with a BindingSource. The two tables with the relevant info are called Channel and Setup. A setup can have many channels while a channel belongs to one setup. In the setup table I have a field called CurrentSetup which indicates the active setup with a bit. I need to show info only from the channels that belong to the active setup. I tried putting "CurrentSetup='True'" on the BindingSource, but that doesn't seem to work because all my data is coming from the ChannelBindingSource which can only read the foreign key (Setup_id) from the Setup table, but can't access the rest of the table it seems.

So to sum it up, my question is how can I filter a BindingSource based on a field from a related table?

I'd add to that that I'm using the Entity Framework (6), and I've read that BindingSources aren't even the recommended way to do this, but it's the only thing I've found that seems to work so far. If I'm way off base with this, and should be doing something else I'm open to that too. I just still find BindingSources in the current (VS 2013) Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using EF then you should be getting only the data you want using LINQ to Entities.  It would be something like this:

```
Dim currentChannels = context.Channels.Where(Function(c) c.Setup.CurrentSetup)
```

That will then give you a list of all the `Channel` entities related to the `Setup` that has its `CurrentSetup` set to `True`.

Comment: Thank you very very kindly for the help. So is it accurate to say that using LINQ to Entities is the preferred way to do databinding with EF as opposed to using a binding source? Once again, thank you very much for the reply. You people who contribute to StackOverflow are heroes.